# gnu ld (cygwin) command does not link properly

Tags: assembly, x86, cygwin, ld

I have two files.
a) kernel_entry.asm (32 bit assembly code)

```
[ bits 32] 
[ extern _start ] 
call _start
jmp $
```

compiled with

```
kernel_entry.o : kernel_entry.asm
<tab>nasm $< -o $@ -f coff
```

b) kernel.c (function name start)

```
void start() 
{
    print_char(); // irrelevant for this question
}
```

compiled with

```
kernel_main.o: kernel.c
<tab>gcc  -static -nostartfiles $<  -L /home/me/OS/driver/ekran  -l ekran -o $@ 

kernel.o : kernel.c
<tab>gcc -ffreestanding -c $< -o $@
```

And kernel_entry.asm's main job is only to jump to start function. When i linked these two files with the following command in makefile

```
kernel.tmp: kernel_entry.o   kernel_main.o
<tab>ld  -o $@ -Ttext 0x1000 kernel_entry.o  kernel_main.o
```

I have the problem that kernel_entry could not jump to start function properly.So i checked the kernel.tmp file with

```
objdump -d kernel.tmp
```

and a section of output is as follows.

```
kernel.tmp:     pei-i386 file format

Disassembly of section .text:

00001000 <.text>:
1000:       e8 fe ff ff ff          call   1003 <.text+0x3>
1005:       eb fe                   jmp    1005 <.text+0x5>
1007:       90                      nop

00001008 <_start>:
1008:       55                      push   %ebp
1009:       89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
100b:       83 ec 18                sub    $0x18,%esp
100e:       c7 44 24 0c 0f 00 00    movl   $0xf,0xc(%esp)
....
....
```

As can be seen above , the code at address 1000 does not jump to start function (at address 1008), and jumps to address 1003 instead that hits nothing.

For now , i solve this problem by only jumping directly to address 1008 in kernel_entry.asm code.

What could be the reason of this?
Thanks in advance...

And this is the code after leaving kernel.c alone (after not linking with any library)

```
kernel.tmp:     pei-i386 file format


Disassembly of section .text:

00001000 <.text>:
1000:       e8 fe ff ff ff          call   1003 <.text+0x3>
1005:       eb fe                   jmp    1005 <.text+0x5>
1007:       90                      nop

00001008 <_start>:
1008:       55                      push   %ebp
1009:       89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
100b:       5d                      pop    %ebp
100c:       c3                      ret
100d:       90                      nop
100e:       90                      nop
100f:       90                      nop
1010:       ff                      (bad)
1011:       ff                      (bad)
1012:       ff                      (bad)
1013:       ff 00                   incl   (%eax)
1015:       00 00                   add    %al,(%eax)
1017:       00 ff                   add    %bh,%bh
1019:       ff                      (bad)
101a:       ff                      (bad)
101b:       ff 00                   incl   (%eax)
101d:       00 00                   add    %al,(%eax)
    ...

00001020 <__CTOR_LIST__>:
1020:       ff                      (bad)
1021:       ff                      (bad)
1022:       ff                      (bad)
1023:       ff 00                   incl   (%eax)
1025:       00 00                   add    %al,(%eax)
    ...

00001028 <__DTOR_LIST__>:
1028:       ff                      (bad)
1029:       ff                      (bad)
102a:       ff                      (bad)
102b:       ff 00                   incl   (%eax)
102d:       00 00                   add    %al,(%eax)
```

Comment: You forgot to show the commands that create `kernel_entry.o` and `kernel_main.o`

Comment: ok , i will edit the question shortly. @Jester

Comment: The command `gcc  -static -nostartfiles $<  -L /home/me/OS/driver/ekran  -l ekran -o $@ ` will produce executable not an object file. It will be named `kernel_main.o`, but it will be fully linked.

Comment: I want to note that i also got this error  before linking kernel.c with library 'ekran' , when the start was the only function without any call.@RossRidge

Comment: What libraries you linked with when creating `kernel_main.o` isn't an issue. That problem is that it's an executable file. Using as an input to the linker isn't going to work, and is why `kernel.tmp` didn't link properly.

Comment: Ok , @RossRidge . Thank you for your help. In linux implementation, the author's command line is **$ld -o kernel.bin -Ttext 0x1000 kernel entry.o kernel.o --oformat binary** . And i did not try that.